# Convetir fecha de formato timestamp a horario central

Tags: linux, bash

Estoy trabajando en un script para solicitar los logs de asterisk, entonces ya me tira los resultados con un `cut`, pero el rango de horas lo tira en formato *timestamp*, lo cual me pidieron que lo cambiara a formato horario central, eso se hace con un `date -d`, pero no se como hacerlo o si hay una posibilidad de hacerlo.

Comment: Pon un trozo de log en la pregunta, más lo que hayas intentado para conseguirlo y los errores que te han dado para que la pregunta sea válida y se te pueda ayudar. Léete [ask], [tour] y [example], gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Para cambiar el formato del *timestamp* a formato horario central, puedes usar el comando `date` con la opción `-d` para especificar el formato de entrada y el formato de salida deseado:

```
date -d "$timestamp" "+%H:%M:%S"
```

Donde `$timestamp` es la variable que contiene el *timestamp* que deseas convertir.

También puedes usar la opción `-u` para establecer el huso horario en UTC, y luego usar la opción `-I` para obtener el formato horario central en formato ISO 8601:

```
date -u -Iseconds
```

Esto te dará el tiempo en formato horario central en formato ISO 8601, por ejemplo: 2021-05-17T15:05:34-05:00

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver tu problema.

Comment: Buena respuesta. Cuida el formato de tu respuesta para que sea leída por todos los miles o cientos de miles que la puedan leer rápidamente en el futuro.